# Pepper plant not blooming\giving fruit

Tags: vegetables, peppers

[image]
[image]

it's been through some times,i've also sprayed it with pesticides
but there haven't been any flowers blooming yet.

thanks in advance!

Comment: what part of the world are you in?

Comment: I live in Israel.

Answer (score 1):

The soil in the pot looks quite dry - if by 'pepper' you mean sweet bell pepper, it should have been potted into a 9 inch pot, not sure of the size of pot you're using. However, given where you are, it's a bit late in the season for a pepper plant to start flowering and then producing fruit, the growing season for these plants is practically over.